# Upload attachments to a page in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, mamp

I've installed a [plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-upload/) that allows a user to upload an attachment to my Wordpress site. In doing so, I can see that the attachments get uploaded to the "wp-content" directory of my Wordpress directory path.

I can then see that the files are uploaded, but when I access the URL, I can see a page that doesn't have a very good design.

[image: Uploaded attachments]

Essentially, I'd like to know how to use the above plugin to upload attachments, and then add these attachments to a page (like an "added attachments page") on Wordpress, that the user can then view.

Comment: Will this be a page of the user's uploaded attachments, or all uploaded attachments (as wp-content/uploads will show all uploads on the cms, images and all)?

Comment: This will be a page of the user's uploaded attachments. In a further question, I'd also like to know if it's possible to "tag" the uploaded attachments, so that the user may then search for it at a later time.

Comment: There will need to be some kind of structure which separates uploads between users so it doesn't show all uploads within the uploads folder. Maybe @aviator's answer will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see all uploaded files through `Dashboard > Media`.
Also, Administrators can view all uploaded files together with associated field data from the plugin’s Settings in Dashboard. The Pro version of the plugin allows users to view their uploaded files, either from the Dashboard, or from a page or post.

Pro version link : [WordPress File Upload Premium](https://www.iptanus.com/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-file-upload/)

---

[Reference](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-upload/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your "Reference" link (which is the plugin that I have installed), is it possible to have the user simply view what they've attached through the wp-content directory? Or in other words, a free plugin that allows me to do so?

Comment: According to the comparison chart given [here](https://www.iptanus.com/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-file-upload/) it's not possible in free version.

Comment: @Adam If this answer is useful then you can accept it. OR let me know if you've any further doubt :)

Comment: I will accept it based on the help :) I'm not sure how to test this though, seeing as how I don't really want to purchase the licence. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: do you know of any good introduction to Wordpress documentation I can have a look at? I'm struggling with the basics, as in how to create single pages and customize them to my look.

Comment: Are you learning WordPress Development or just want to know how to use WordPress?

Comment: Both I guess. I'd like to know how to use Wordpress, but then how to actually create/customize my website using Wordpress, which I guess would be the development? Sorry if I don't understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139750/discussion-between-aviator-and-adam).